# Are css styles applied differently in ie7 for rails error pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-7

I've come across a weird bug for ie7 where the css styles get applied differently when I access "/400.html" and "/500.html" directly as opposed to being redirected to it by a controller.

The controller code for redirection is:

```
respond_to do |format|  
  format.html { render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :status => "404 Not Found" }  
  format.all { render :nothing => true, :status => "404 Not Found" }  
end
```

The styles are exactly the same for ff and safari. I've tried clearing the cache and restarting the server several times as well.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you call render :file, the current layout is not applied. Are you including a stylesheet in a default layout that is *not* included in the 404 page? If so, you need to call

```
render :file => whatever, :status => "404 Not Found", :layout => true
```